# I need an example that i can use as a template for JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have an assignment where I have to make a test plan and a unit test in java. I was wanting some help and an answer provided so I can use them as examples for the future.

The instructor's instructions: Complete a test plan and unit tests for your Card and Deck ADTs.  Implement your final ADTs.

I have made two classes and I have already made some unit Tests but I just feel like they could be better.

```
@Test
    void HideTest()
    {



    }

    @Test
    void showTest()
    {



    }
```

```
//this method shows the card
public void show()

{

    this.visible = true;

}

//this method hides the card
public void hide()

{

    this.visible = false;

}
```

```
I expect a Junit test that runs correctly.
```

Comment: The method show and hide doesn't seem to do something valuable to write a unit test.

Comment: Re "I just feel like they could be better" - what exactly do you need help with? Writing effective tests? Feedback on the effectiveness of your test so far? Suggestions on writing test plans? If you can be more specific on what you're looking for help with you'll be more likely to get some answers.

Comment: "but I just feel like they could be better" - your tests are not testing anything yet, so that's true. But you need to figure out for yourself what you want to test (what should be the end state you want to assert for after doing what operating) and then try to implement that test.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you need some help writing tests for your code take a look at https://playground.diffblue.com if you put the class for your card in it will produce sample unit tests for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating this class in eclipse. You can create standard unit tests in eclipse as described in this tutorial: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/11wi/eclipse-tutorial/junit.shtml